# Rogue pvp rotation Cataclysm 4.3?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I played Wrath of the Lich King as rogue up to lvl 80. I did some pvp but I never actually was really successful. Most of the kills I got were because of the difference between gear. I've returned to the game late in Cataclysm& will soon be 85 and want to go pvp but have no idea what to do. I am an Orc Rogue btw.

Specifically, I'd like to know what the preferred spec for pvp is.  It seems that most rogues go for subtetly as their main tree and not assasination(or even combat) in pvp. Why is this?

Given the best spec, how do I play it? What would be the standard combat rotation? (Examples vs specific classes would be particularly helpful here.)

Comment: I don't' see too many "full guides" on this site. Most questions just get pointed to http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12/what-are-some-well-written-guides-for-world-of-warcraft - or pointed at Elitist Jerks which is constantly updated, you just need a little time investment. http://elitistjerks.com/f78/ . Generally, considering how fast this information changes, I believe it is best left to a community that focuses on constantly evolving strategies in World of Warcraft.

Comment: Well, I could have split this questions in 7 questions and then It would be the same result. Also, if you look closely this isn't a full guid, but a pvp rogue guide more or less but it covers more points that's why I said full. Maybe I should have used full(ish) guide. And also, I'm not intereseted in any version changes other the specific 4.3 version. And as I stated, at more than half the points I already have a good answer in my mind but I also want this to help others. If this isn't ok, I'll just re-edit the question leaving 2-3 points which I'm more interested in.

Comment: I agree with Resorath - while I could provide a detailed answer for this question (and recently answered a similar one about warlock PvP), I don't think it suits the SE style very well.  Also, you shouldn't ever ask a question on SE because you want to help other people - never second-guess what the community wants, just ask what *you* want and hope that it will be useful to other people.  If you want to help people, you should answer questions.

Comment: @Fofole I recommend you go look up [Mercader](http://www.youtube.com/user/MercaderGaming) on Youtube. The guy is an excellent Rogue and he posts quite a few tips and tricks videos. He is also a pretty boss FPS player.

Comment: You have wrapped too many questions in one. I agree with the feeling that it'd be better to have each question be handled separately (I'm not sure we can answer all of them.)

Comment: Ok I restrained the questions to my main priority question. I hope this would fit the Q&A format.

Comment: Isn't this question too localized? I mean, I believe all the WoW servers will move towards 4.4 and later patches, Mists of Pandaria, etc., which could possibly make this question and answers useless for future visitors (there will be no 4.3 servers).

Comment: @sarmackie by that standard all questions about MMO's are too localized. So too are all questions we've ever had about Minecraft.  Or any other game that gets frequent balance or content updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't played WoW in a while, but WoW builds are constantly changing. Because of this I think you'll find a constantly updating source helpful. I always found great information at Elitistjerks, mmo-champs and even in the wow-forums.

[This](http://www.mmo-champion.com/threads/1080950-Combat-Rogue-PvP-Compendium-4.3) a good guide for rogues in cataclysm. His update is from this month, so I believe this is a accurate guide.

Some good sample [here](http://gotwarcraft.com/guides/classguides/subtletyrogue.php), [here](http://roguebuilds.com/) and [here](http://eu.battle.net/wow/en/forum/topic/2588768920)

Ok some explanation now:

**Why subtlety:**

> Subtlety rogues present a combination of DPS and utility
> allowing them to do well in both PvP and PvE. In the DPS race an
> Assassination or Combat build might pump out more overall damage, but
> Subtlety is more fun and more flexible. And Assassination doesn't have
> Shadowstep.

**Subtlety rotations:**

> PvP:
>
> There is no PvP "rotation." Try to lock up your opponents and burst
>
> them down when you can. Glyphed Garrote silences casters Keep
>
> Recuperate up at all times. The HAT talent helps with this, providing
> extra combo points. You might even be able to start a fight with Recup
> running. Try to keep Slice and Dice up, but not at the expense of
> stuns. Rupture is good Vs stealthers. Learn to use Shadowdance and
> glyph it (two more seconds.) Save your Shadowstep, if possible, until
> the opponent escapes (eg: Blink,) then use it to catch up.

Check out the links. they are more complete, with Gems, runes, professions even races.
Sorry for the link only post, i used to see some http://jsfiddle.net/ posts on stackoverflow, and i like post the font with a link, by my mistake (was late) i forget post some content with it. Thank you for your -1

Comment: Hello again! Although your link is helpful, we discourage users from posting an answer which is little more than a link. This is because if your link were to ever die, then the answer would no longer be of any help to any future visitors of our site. Due to this we consider it good practice to provide a small exceprt of the link so that it answers the OPs question to some degree (and then users can click on the link for more detail). This is probably why your question was down voted.

Comment: LoL you are following me =) Well thank you for the extra info, but i used the link as a complament. too bad that it didn't look like what i intended to do. Well, well, well, nothing to do here. i guess. PS: wow always change, tree, skill and other stuff, this is why i don't agree with the down vote...

Comment: Ah okay, I see what you were trying to get at now. I've edited your answer to include your statement about how WoW builds are always changing.

Comment: Agree on sub spec and "There is no PvP "rotation." Try to lock up your opponents and burst". Will add, make sure you keep hemo on your target and remain behind your target at all times so they can't attack you and you can spam backstab. Also get the hemo glyph if you have not done so already. Remember you're not a ranged DPS nor a tank, so in and out fighting styles is your play, if you can't do what you need to do quickly, vanish/cloak of shadows and reset the fight.

Comment: @Fofole That's a silly rule. Bad answers deserve downvotes. Good answers deserve upvotes. This *was* a bad answer, so I downvoted it. Then it got edited and improved, so I changed my vote. Working As Intended.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz - disagree, if an answer is wrong or "bad" then it wont get up voted, this balances itself out when a good answer receives up votes. IMO down voting only discourages people to not post answers, however I don't make the rules on SE. Getting into meta discussion here though, my bad!

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Hi, thanks for change your mind. i don't agree with downvote, like Jared and Fofole. next time (maybe) try ask for improvement before downvote like Wipqozn. He said in the first comment what i need to improve my answer, so i did. if was not him, i was not going to change it. But... as Jared also said, this is a subject to Meta not gaming, sorry for the misdirection that the comments get into.

Comment: btw, @Fofole i hope the answer (i saw was accept as the best answer) was good enough for you. If you need something else, just ask.